# C# - Using Custom Annotations?

Tags: c#, annotations

I created this Annotation class
This example might not make sense because It'll always throw an exception but I'm still using it as I am just trying to explain what my question is.
My annotation never gets called for some reasons any solutions?

```
public class AuthenticationRequired : System.Attribute
{
   public AuthenticationRequired()
   {
      // My break point never gets hit why?
      throw new Exception("Throw this to see if annotation works or not");
   }
}

[AuthenticationRequired]
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // My break point get here
}
```

Comment: Here you have how to access and read your custom annotation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx#Y109

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> My annotation never gets called for some reasons any solutions?

This is kind of a misunderstanding of attributes. Attributes effectively exist to add metadata to certain parts of your code (classes, properties, fields, methods, parameters, etc.) The compiler takes the information in the attribute and bakes it into the IL that it spits out when it's done eating your source code.

Attributes by themselves don't do anything unless someone consumes them. That is, someone at some point has to discover your attribute and then take action on it. They sit in the IL of your assembly, but they don't do anything unless someone finds them and acts on them. It's only when they do this will an instance of the attribute be instantiated. The typical way to do this is using reflection.

To obtain the attributes at runtime, you have to say something like

```
var attributes = typeof(Foo)
                    .GetMethod("Window_Loaded")
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthenticationRequired), true)
                    .Cast<AuthenticationRequired>();

foreach(var attribute in attributes) {
    Console.WriteLine(attribute.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't compile, I don't have a compiler handy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is it possible to make it so that when a method has a specific attribute a specific block of code gets called? Would that be considered bad practice? Let's say I want every method with "Log" attribute to log the time. I am trying to use this method to reuse code

Comment: @aryaxt: Yes, it's possible to do that. But you need something to build that for you (you can do it yourself, but there are tools available that will do it for you). What you are looking for is something that will dynamically build a proxy for you. These concerns are often called cross-cutting concerns, and this type of programming is called aspect oriented programming. If you look at the interception capabilities in Castle Windsor, for example, you will see how it can be done: http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/interceptors.html

Comment: @jason The link is broken. Do you have a fix?